# A word for someone who "does justice" to their (nick)name

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idiom-requests

I'm looking for an expression (preferably a single word) that denotes someone whose name or title fits them ironically too well. Names and nicknames are usually figurative, but I'm looking for idioms that I can use to make some word play in situations where they could be taken literally.

A few examples of what I want:

> - John the Headhunter took the meaning of <sub>person who does justice to their name</sub> too far. Literal murder is not part of his job description.
> - Mary "Smoking Hot" Smith, <sub>ironically doing justice to her name</sub>, did not manage to leave the building in time and was swallowed by the flames.
> - Joe "Please Don't Call Me Joe 'Joe Miller' Miller" Miller, as expected of a <sub>someone with that nickname</sub>, quit the interview after feeling improperly addressed. 
>     <sub>This is actually a [real person](http://lol.gamepedia.com/Joe_Miller).</sub>

Comment: @Cascabel Thanks for the feedback. How do you think I could make it clearer? I must say I'm having a bad time trying to put my thoughts in words. I'll try to edit to make it better.

Comment: Well, I made a few edits to try to better express what I want, I hope it makes a bit more sense now. Thanks for the help, _Hot Licks_, I was already editing, but left the title as you suggested. I realize it's still messy, so I appreciate any feedback anyone can leave me to make it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### "Aptly monikered" / "Aptly monickered"

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/moniker):

> moniker or monicker (ˈmɒnɪkə  )
>   *noun*
>   *slang*
>
> a person's name or nickname

Your examples could scan as follows:

The *aptly monickered* John the Headhunter...
The *aptly monickered* Mary "Smoking Hot" Smith...
etc.

Answer (score 7):

I think the phrase you're searching for in these examples is "living up to their nickname":

> John the Headhunter took the meaning of **living up to his nickname** too far. Literal murder is not part of his job description.

That does sound a bit off in that example. It's better to just say "lived up to":

> - John the Headhunter **lived up to** his nickname by committing murder on the job.
> - Mary "Smoking Hot" Smith **lived up to** her nickname by being swallowed up by the flames after not managing to leave the building on time.
> - Joe "Please Don't Call Me Joe 'Joe Miller' Miller" Miller, as expected,
>   **lived up to** his nickname after being improperly addressed in an interview.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. You can also simply "live up to your name", e.g. Usain Bolt.